# "Yum Update" reinstalling removed packages

Tags: fedora, yum

On my Fedora 19 system, `yum update` attempts to reinstall a large number packages I have previously removed. This should not happen, as the packages listed are not installed and should not be suggested by yum. How can I make yum work in the expected manner - with updates suggesting only upgrades to preinstalled packages.

*Background*: I have been trying out new DEs - installing and removing them as I go. Currently, I'm in a DE-less state, booting directly into a tty terminal. My system has no (or a few hidden) xfce or cinnamon packages to "upgrade", yet the package manager is suggesting 300 packages to install, totaling 600M of new install.

Terminal output gist:

https://gist.github.com/Redoubts/29400f0b98cd13120a6a#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - It's not possible to disallow installing any packages from the depenency chain. Either you install all of them or drop those who depends on unwanted packages.

In some cases, when the package from a dependency chain is required only during some specific stages of installation (say for execution of a pre- or post-install scripts), it's possible to remove thise package later, after the complete installation. But that's not what you want I suppose.

Comment: In my particular issue, there are two classes of packages being installed - updates and their dependencies. It does make sense that dependencies are being pulled along, and disabling that would likely be detrimental. But the packages marked as "updates" really should be there. For example Thunar (xfce file manager) is marked as needing an update, even though it's not installed at all.